# Accesing base url from constant class

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsurl

I have created a class "AppConstant" and defined a global constant for "baseURL" like this. 
  **APPCostant.h**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

extern NSString * const appBaseUrl;

@interface APPConstant : NSObject
@end
```

`  **AppConstant.m**

```
#import "APPConstant.h"

@implementation APPConstant

/** defining base url of server **/
NSString *const AppbaseURL = @"http://www.exapmle.com/";

@end
```

Now I have imported `AppConstant.h` in my class where I want to use the base url, and trying to built my url like below, but I am getting the compile-time error.

**Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_appBaseUrl", referenced from:
      -[KKSearchViewController searchRequest] in KKSearchViewController.o**

```
 NSURL *url =[NSURL URLWithString:@"search" relativeToURL:[NSURL URLWithString:appBaseUrl]];
```

I am not sure, whats wrong here. What I want to achieve is little bit cleaner and reusable code, So that I don't have to change the url in every class.

Comment: Is it really at this line? Likely you want to replace `appBaseURL` with `MONAppsBaseUrl`.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake...I have updated the question. Please, check now.

Comment: Likely APPConstant.m is not compiled and linked. Please, check that.

Comment: You say "from constant class". Does APPConstant actually declare a class?  Can you show it? Or is it just a declaration of a global?

Comment: @Paulw11: Yes I have created a class"APPConstant" sublassed to NSObject. What you wanna see?

Comment: Well, if `appBaseURL` is a class member then you can't just refer to it as `appBaseURL`, it will be `APPConstant.appBaseURL`. Show the class file `AppConstanf.m`

Comment: @Amin : How to check that, It gives error when I try to build the project

Comment: @Paulw11 : Updated the question, as asked by you

Comment: There are two options: 1. Select *AppContent.m* in the navigator and check in the file inspector (on the right side) the *Target Membership*. It should be checked. 2. Select your project in the file inspector, the target in the next right column, *Build Phases* at the top. It should appear in *Compile Sources* group below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of ways you could achieve what you are after and, unfortunately, you have kind of mixed up both approaches.

The first approach is a global variable.  The second is a class property.

In your .h file you have a global variable, while in your .m file you (kind of) have a class property.

If you want to use the global variable approach, simply remove the `@implementation` from your .m file:

**AppConstant.m**

```
 #import "AppConstant.h"

 NSString * const appBaseUrl = @"http://someserver.com";
```

You can then simply refer to `appBaseUrl` as you do in your `URLWithString` call.

The second approach is to use a class level property.  Unfortunately Objective-C doesn't have class level properties, so you have to declare a class level function that returns your required value.  You can, however, refer to 0 argument methods in Objective C using the `.` accessor, so it *looks* like a class level property.

**AppConstant.h**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface AppConstant : NSObject

+(NSString *)appBaseUrl;

@end
```

**AppConstant.m**

```
#import "AppConstant.h"

@implementation AppConstant

+(NSString *)appBaseUrl {
    return(@"http://someserver.com");
}

@end
```

In this case you would use `AppConstant.appBaseUrl` when you wanted the value.

Comment: second Approach looks more elegant to me, what is your recommendation?

Comment: Yes, I would avoid the use of globals.  Using the object gives you a "namespace" and makes it clearer where the value comes from.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you are trying to call API by appending path in baseUrl in each viewcontroller, But its better to do all the api call related tasks in One Helper Class by passing the the path to it and sending the response in callback to the sender viewController.

In Api Helper Class

```
 #import "Apicaller.h"
 static NSString *baseUrl = @"http://baseUrl/";

 @implementation Apicaller

 +(void)postToUrl:(NSString*)appendString parametersPassed:(NSDictionary*)parameters completion:(void (^) (NSMutableDictionary *response))completion{
      NSString *url = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", baseUrl,appendString];
     //Do urlrequest and return response in completion
     completion(responseObject);


 }


@end
```

And you can call this Class Method from Anywhere you wish

```
  [Apicaller postToUrl:path parametersPassed:parameter completion:^(NSMutableDictionary *response) {

       //This is callback Response
        NSLog(@"this is response %@", response);


    }];
```

Comment: Yes, my ultimate goal is the same, but can't upvote your answer.

Comment: The answer of context is a bit different from the question, But i'll accept it if doesn't get any related answer.

Answer (score -1):

use prefix file instead of manual importing files

Add new PCH file to the project: New file > Other > PCH file.
At the Target's Build Settings option, set the value of Prefix Header to your PCH file name, with the project name as prefix (i.e. for project named TestProject and PCH file named MyPrefixHeaderFile, add the value TestProject/MyPrefixHeaderFile.pch to the plist).

TIP: You can use things like $(SRCROOT) or $(PROJECT_DIR) to get to the path of where you put the .pch in the project.
At the Target's Build Settings option, set the value of Precompile Prefix Header to YES.

[for example check this site](https://techfuzionwithsam.wordpress.com/2014/11/29/how-to-add-pch-or-prefix-pch-file-in-xcode-6/)

Comment: yes its not recommended to use but its give you easy access of you base url in any of your project file so its really helpfull